# Call to undefined method Cake\ORM\Entity::query() CakePhp

Tags: php, sql, web, cakephp, orm

I'm using cakePhp 3.x and I want to call my controller and make a query but it throw me this error : "Call to undefined method Cake\ORM\Entity::query()"

I think i've done everything well because I've included the right library here's my code :

```
use Cake\ORM\Entity;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
public function delete()
{
    $this->loadModel('Products');
    $conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');
    $id = !empty($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '';
    $data = $this->request->data;
    $product = TableRegistry::get('Products')->newEntity($data);

    $query = $product->query();
    $query->delete()
    ->where(['id' => $id])
    ->execute();

    $this->autoRender = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
    $product = TableRegistry::get('Products')->newEntity($data);
```

with :

```
    $product = TableRegistry::get('Products');
```